# "Abstract classes" in Svelte

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, svelte-component

I am fairly new to Svelte and frontend (I mostly have experience with Rust/C++/Python), please excuse me if this is a dumb question.

I am trying to display different types of time-indexed data and I have a variable "timestamp" that the user can edit. I want to display the matching item for each of my lists for a given timestamp.

Let's say my lists are temperature readings and rainfall readings.

```
interface Temperature {
temperature: number
}
interface Rainfall {
rainfall: number
}
A = [{"timestamp" : 0, "temperature": 20}, {"timestamp": 1, "temperature": 25}, {"timestamp" : 2, "temperature": 28}]   
B = [{"timestamp" : 0, "rainfall": 200}, {"timestamp" :1, "rainfall": 210}, {"timestamp": 2, "rainfall": 220}]
```

I have Svelte components Temperature and Rainfall that can display the corresponding Typescript interfaces. I don't know how I can abstract over the fact that each type of data has a timestamp and a way how it is displayed as a Svelte component. In an OO language, I would use something like an abstract class that has a display() method that would return the corresponding Svelte component.

Is there a way in Svelte/JS to write unified code for selecting the datum matching a timestamp from a list and then display that datum with its corresponding Svelte component?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property for the component to display the data and then show it using [`<svelte:component>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-component). Though, if the data comes from a server, you cannot pass the component like that.

I would probably use a mapping via a `type` property instead. E.g.

```js
interface Temperature {
  type: 'temperature';
  temperature: number;
}
interface Rainfall {
  type: 'rainfall';
  rainfall: number;
}

type Datum = Temperature | Rainfall;
```

```html
<script lang="ts">
  // ...
  import TemperatureComponent from '...';
  import RainfallComponent from '...';

  export let item: Datum;

  const displayMapping: Record<Datum['type'], SvelteComponent> = {
    temperature: TemperatureComponent,
    rainfall: RainfallComponent,
  }
</script>

<svelte:component this={displayMapping[item.type]} {...item} />
```

Alternatively you could just use an `{#if}/{:else if}` chain based on the `type`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Is it Typescript best practice to have a "type" field for creating an enum type?

Comment: It is fairly common as it allows to be JSON-serialized. Note that TypeScript also has its own `enum` *type*, which maps named members to number or 
 string values. Depending on how the `type` is used, it might make sense to use that, e.g. if you have numberic IDs that get saved in some database. Often simply creating a discriminating union using string literals is a convenient approach as TS can make this much safer by not allowing arbitrary string values.